# minicom dialing out error

Tags: linux, phone

I'm running minicom on Ubuntu 10.04 with a Huawei e220 and an AT&T SIM card. As directed by http://bit.ly/16ODGG, I was able to send an SMS to myself and several other phones across carriers.

```
device: /dev/ttyUSB0
bps: 115200 8N1
hardware: No
software: Yes
```

The next step I would like to do is to be able to dial out. However, when I attempt to do so, via

```
ATDTxxxxxxxxxx
```

I will get a `NO CARRIER` output. I've been Google-ing this error, and it seems the most consistent answer is for me to use `pppconfig` to dial out - but from my understanding, this will utilize the *data* connection on my phone, and make the phone call via the internet, and not *voice*, as per the minutes plan of my phone company.

Is there a way I can make the call over voice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Resolved! In order to avoid this:

[image]

I emailed a professor that I know, and he has resolved the issue - sad to say, e220 does not support voice calls. As per http://bit.ly/wSDoGW, I was able to check for voice compatibility in `minicom`:

```
AT+FCLASS=?
+FCLASS: (0-1)

OK
```

For voice support, the list of numbers returned by FCLASS must include 8 - thus, this particular return indicates voice is (unfortunately) not supported by my modem.